# Correct usage of package RTriangle in R

Tags: r, triangulation, delaunay

I'm trying to compunte a triangulation in R with package RTriangle. Here's my code

```
pslgobj<-pslg(coord_rid[,1:2],S=Boundaries)
```

Where `coord_rid` contains all the coordinates of 911 points, and `Boundaries` contains the segments for the region boundaries (connections from point #580 to #911).

So I can compute the (Delaunay) triangulation

```
mesh_rid<-triangulate(pslgobj,Y=TRUE,D=TRUE)
```

But if I control the number of points used in the triangulation

```
dim(mesh_rid$P)
```

I can see 1006 points, not 911. How can I prohibit the insertion of new points in `trinagulate` command?

Comment: Can we have your data, or a minimal example that reproduces the problem with random or small data?

Comment: The dataset is composed by the spatial collocation of municipalities in Veneto (italian region) and by an approssimation of boundaries (with a polygon). How can I give you the RData file?

Comment: Near Venezia, the boundaries of Veneto is very complex. There is a greater concentration of points. The insertion of points is in this part of the domain... Maybe this is the problem? Delaunay triangulation is allowed to insert new points?

Comment: Have you tried `Y=1`, as said in the doc?